# why i get errors like multiple constructors not allowed, duplicate define posts and duplicate define common etc. in Angular?

Tags: angular

this is the problem which I got in angular, So I am trying to view all three section on my website but it's not  comes one by one  but three of these not shown properly on website. so error in base on view in my opinion and suggest me the proper code for this problem

[image]

Comment: You simply can’t have mulitple constructors in a javascript class..?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code and/or error messages. Post the actual text instead. This makes it easier for people to help you and for others to find this question in a search if they have similar issues in the future.  Please read over the answers to this question to understand a bit more about this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, and  i found  the solution of this error ,next time i will  ask  the 
 question as you suggest.